# i need explanation to a way of implementing cross validation in trControl function in caret

Tags: machine-learning, r, cross-validation

given this example :

```
# Example of Stacking algorithms
# create submodels
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, savePredictions=TRUE, classProbs=TRUE)
algorithmList <- c('lda', 'rpart', 'glm', 'knn', 'svmRadial')
set.seed(seed)
models <- caretList(Class~., data=dataset, trControl=control, methodList=algorithmList)
results <- resamples(models)
summary(results)
```

should we always give the entire data set to the train function and it will automate the splitting of test and train and evaluate on the test set
or should i give it the train set  and evaluate by my self on the test data set ?